# How can I remove double quotes for multiple columns data at a time

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I remove double quotes for multiple columns data at a time in MySQL?

Like

```
Name     Country_Code    phone 
"Ravi".     "91".        "809562"
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to replace in a select query or update the table or are seeking a shortcut to avoid specifying all columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(Name, '"', ""), 
    REPLACE(Country_Code, '"',""), 
    REPLACE(phone, '"', "") 
FROM table_name;
```

You can make update to your table with:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    Name = REPLACE(Name, '"', ""), 
    Country_Code = REPLACE(Country_Code, '"',""), 
    phone = REPLACE(phone, '"', "");
```

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: That means your question is not clear, it's like you're trying to update your table. I will edit the answer, so you can try it. @VeeraReddy